# Min of multiple case statements

Tags: sql, case, sql-server-2000, min

Using SSMS 2012 but SQL Server 2000.

I have a query that has among other things 4 columns that are calculated through lengthy  case statements. I need one more column added that shows the smallest value of these 4 columns. In the final form does not require the 4 columns to remain in the results as long as the last col has the smallest value. Below is the code I am currently using along with a sample of results. in the sample of results I have included what I want for the Final Tier col. Also I am new to SQL so if there is a cleaner way to do this same task please feel free to teach me. :)

```
Select 
,Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) as ADT
,Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) as AMT
,Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
  Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2) as ADL
,Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
  Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2) as AML

,case 
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 3500 and 1000000 then '1'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 2000 and 3499.99 then '2'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 1500 and 1999.99 then '3'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 1000 and 1499.99 then '4'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 750  and 999.99  then '5'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 500  and 749.99  then '6'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 300  and 499.99  then '7'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 150  and 299.99  then '8'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 75   and 149.99  then '9'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 40   and 74.99   then '10'
    when Round(Sum(S.TWin)/Nullif(Count(Distinct S.GamingDate),0),2) between 15   and 39.99   then '11'
    Else null
End as "ADT Tier"
,case
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 21000 and 1000000 then '1'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 12000 and 20999   then '2'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 9000  and 11999   then '3'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 6000  and 8999    then '4'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 4500  and 5999    then '5'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 3000  and 4499    then '6'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 1800  and 2999    then '7'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 900   and 1799    then '8'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 450   and 899     then '9'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 240   and 349     then '10'
    when Round(Sum(S.Twin)/Nullif(count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate)),0),2) between 90    and 239     then '11'
    Else null
End as "AMT Tier"
,case
    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 3500 and 1000000 then '1'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 2000 and 3499.99 then '2'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 1500 and 1999.99 then '3'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 1000 and 1499.99 then '4'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 750  and 999.99  then '5'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 500  and 749.99  then '6'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 300  and 499.99  then '7'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 150  and 299.99  then '8'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 75   and 149.99  then '9'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 40   and 74.99   then '10'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/Count(Distinct S.GamingDate)),2)
         between 15   and 39.99   then '11'

    Else null
End as "ADL Tier"
,case
    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 21000 and 1000000 then '1'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 12000 and 20999   then '2'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 9000  and 11999   then '3'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 6000  and 8999    then '4'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 4500  and 5999    then '5'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 3000  and 4499    then '6'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 1800  and 2999    then '7'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 900   and 1799    then '8'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 450   and 899     then '9'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 240   and 349     then '10'

    when Round(((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)+
         Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn + S.CreditIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end))/count(Distinct Month(S.GamingDate))),2)
         between 90    and 239     then '11'

    Else null
End as "AML Tier"

From  dbo.CDS_STATDAY as S

Where S.GamingDate Between '06/1/2014' and '08/31/2014'
  And S.IDType = 'P'
  And S.StatType <> 'Poker'

Group by S.Meta_ID
```

Results

```
Player ID    ADT     AMT      ADL     AML      ADT Tier    AMT Tier    ADL Tier    AML Tier    Final Tier
114          498.26  4484.31  394.99  3554.90  7           6           7           6             6
144          59.42   257.50   61.46   266.34   10          10          10          10           10
316          0.29    0.29     -13.1   -13.1    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL         NULL
573          3.09    6.18     60      120      NULL        NULL        10          11           10
```

I am not sure if this is best done with subquery, nested case, or something I have no idea even exists.

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?

Comment: I am super new to sql stuff so I am not real sure what you mean by RDMS but I think you are wanting to know I am using T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something wrong with your approach, but maybe it would be better to treat this kind of thing at the application level rather than in a query.

Comment: I agree with this however the big boss said no he wants in in the query.

Answer (score 0):

First, transform your query into a view.
The, create a new query over the view, with the fields already calculated and you can compare the fields with each other.

Comment: Ok I will google what a view is and how to use that. :)